# Can network admin see what's goining on inside XP Mode on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-monitoring, windows

I have Windows 7, and installed XP Mode in order to run certain work programs that won't run in Windows 7.  Although both Windows 7 and XP Mode share the same physical connections, they have different IP addresses.  Is it possible for a network admin to see what's going on with regard to internet traffic when operating inside of XP Mode?  My workplace has banned social media, and every now and then if I am searching for something on google or yahoo, it will take me to sites that could be considered social... I have my browser set to delete all browsing history and delete cookies when I exit the browser, but want to know if XP Mode can be monitored same way as XP or Win7 can...

Comment: This isn't really a useful SF quesiton. Deleting your browser history and cookies doesn't prevent your network admin knowing where you have been and what you have been doing whether using XP mode or Windows 7 directly, it just keeps you from seeing it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they can. And this question is off-topic and *very* unwelcome here. We are those administrators you try to circumvent.